# Webview does not show onConsoleMessage in android

Tags: android, webview

I have used webview

with the reference http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

```
  myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
              Log.d("MyApplication", cm.message() + " -- From line "
                                   + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
                                   + cm.sourceId() );
              return true;
            }
            public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
                Log.d("MyApplication", message + " -- From line "
                                     + lineNumber + " of "
                                     + sourceID);
              }
});
```

but still m not get log Logcat

Please help me out

Comment: If Log.d doesn't show up, try Log.e. Worked for me with the emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears some devices (HTC Desire and some others) with specific OS (mine had 2.3.3) do not display messages in Logcat window and it seems console.log does not work for them. I found a nice workaround using JavaScript Interface to overcome the issue: [Android Console via JS interface](https://web.archive.org/web/20140209000107/http://www.stevenmarkford.com/solution-to-onconsolemessage-not-working-for-android/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case (I have Samsung Note 4 running Android 6.0), `onConsoleMessage` is called only if I set

```java
myWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
```

and when I open the Chrome remote device debugger to inspect the webview. But obviously this is not quite helpful since I can already see the console output on the debugger window.